# Странное поведение во vue js 3 версии composition Api функция setup

Tags: массивы, vue.js, ref

Моя проблема в следующем: я пробегаюсь по массиву через v-for, добавляю ключ key, каждую ссылку на элемент добавляю в массив с помощью биндинга ref на функцию, где аргумент добляю с помощью push на массив. Дабы оптимизировать анимацию решил удалять класс с реактивной ссылкой при каждой прокрутке страницы. Но когда решил вывести в консоль массив с элементами, увидел следующую картину: в массиве пополняются записи, хотя если же класс таким образом не изменять, то статично в массиве 3 ссылки на элементы. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: чтобы получше разобраться нужен код

Comment: <div class="products-block__cards__card" 
            v-for="card in watchers" 
            :key="card.id" 
            :ref="(el)=>{cardsAll.push(el)}"
            :class="{'products-block__cards__card_active':isActive}">

Comment: let isActive = ref(false)                                                                                                        window.addEventListener('wheel', (e)=>{
    photosIndex +=e.deltaY/100
        if(photosIndex<cardLenght && photosIndex >=0){
            cardsRef.value.style.left = -photosIndex * 300 + 'px'
            
            isActive = true ***
            isActive = false ***

Comment: сейчас я, конечно, всё сделал в лоб. По ссылке classList.add. Возникает вопрос: можно ли как-нибудь это оптимизировать?